# Closing Handler, removing callbacks

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle, android-handler

In my app i have few `Activities`. The problem is that when I want to close an app, one of my activities won't terminate and when I reopen the app this activity is brought up first.

As far as I am concerned this may be the problem with use of the `Handler`.

In this activity i use `Handler` within `onTouchListener` to spin an image using the `Runnable`, while the button is pressed. After releasing the button I remove callbacks and call another method to start next activity.

```
    public void ListenTo(){
    MatchTime.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        long time_start=0;
        long time_end=0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            matchHandler = new Handler();
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {                
                time_start=System.currentTimeMillis();
                matchHandler.post(matchAction);
                return true;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {                  
                time_end=System.currentTimeMillis();
                long TimeCounted=time_end-time_start;
                matchHandler.removeCallbacks(matchAction);
                matchHandler = null;
                SaveAndSend(TimeCounted);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        Runnable matchAction = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Face = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MatchTimeImage);
                Face.setRotation(Face.getRotation()+9);                     
                matchHandler.postDelayed(this, 25);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

My question is:

What am I doing wrong that `Handler` thread won't stop until Android terminates it itself?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience calling this worked great!

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

In the docs for removeCallbacksAndMessages it says...
"Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is token. **If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed**."

see this post for [removeCallbacksAndMessages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is strange. Main thread (I think you call it Handler thread) will run until your app is totally destroyed. Hander is not a thread. It's an interface for message queue which is despatched for instance by some thread.

Your problem is that you removing Runnable from wrong handler. Every time you create a new Handler (matchHandler = new Handler()). Every handler has it's own queue of pending runnables. So you create new handler and add runnable. Then you create another handler and remove runnable (obviosly there wasn't one, because it's another handler). You should create only one handler and add and remove runnables from it.

Comment: You are right, I was not correct in my question. What I want to know is where/how I should create this Handler once and for all? I moved matchHandler = new Handler() to onCreate and got the same result as previously.

Comment: Maybe you set Listener several times? Every time you create new listener you create new matchAction. I cant see all your code. But if you use same handler and runnable instance post and removeCallbacks should work.

Answer (score 0):

pass null in  removeCallbacksAndMessages like

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```